# "Page not found" due to modification of slugs in Wordpress, how do I fix it?

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks, slug, yoast

When performing an SEO optimization on Wordpress (with the Yoast plugin) I modified some slugs. Now within those modified pages I find links that take me to "page not found", broken links. I've already tried modifying permalinks, but it wasn't fixed. Do you know how I could fix it?
Thanks a lot!

Modify the URL slugs, later test the internal links and they give me the result "page not found"

Comment: Hi
There are many plugins available for redirection like https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/ try using them. Hope that may help you